# Get # of contiguous hits and their first/last index in a NumPy array

Tags: python, numpy, python-itertools

Here is an itertools solution that returns a list of the lengths of each contiguous block.  Here a contiguous block is a run of 1s without breaks in between.  Is there a way to also have itertools return the index associated with each block?

```
import itertools
import numpy as np

stack = np.zeros((10,10))
stack[0] = 1
stack[5,:5] = 1
contiguous_hits = [ (sum( 1 for _ in group )) for row in stack for key, group in itertools.groupby(row)  if key ]
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Why `sum( 1 for _ in group ))`? Why not just `sum(group)`?

Comment: I think originally I was using True/False values instead of integers

Comment: Okay. So are you counting only contiguous ones?

Comment: Yeah that's correct.. I should make that clearer

Comment: What do you mean by contiguous? what's the answer for `[1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1]`?

Comment: Contiguous means connected by a border, so 1,1 are contiguous because they border each other.  How many sets of 1s are connected by a border in [1,1,1,0,1,1]?  edit* And how many 1s are in each set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one vectorized method -

```
def start_stop_per_row(stack):
    z = np.zeros((stack.shape[0],1),dtype=stack.dtype)
    z_ext = np.column_stack((z,stack,z))
    mask = z_ext[:,1:] != z_ext[:,:-1]
    idx = np.argwhere(mask)
    return pd.DataFrame({'row':idx[::2,0],'start':idx[::2,1],'stop':idx[1::2,1]-1})
```

Sample run -

```
In [108]: stack
Out[108]: 
array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])

In [109]: start_stop_per_row(stack)
Out[109]: 
   row  start  stop
0    0      0     9
1    2      1     4
2    2      7     9
3    5      0     4
```

Comment: This solution doesn't work when an array contains runs of length 2. The offset equality produces a single True for these, which messes up the strategy of grabbing every second element from the result of argwhere (indices of nonzero elements). The arrays of start and stop indices often end up having different lengths.